# How to monitor an AWS Glue Workflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-glue, aws-glue-workflow

I have a Glue Workflow consisting of multiple AWS Glue jobs, and I want to be alerted when it fails. Currently I have CloudWatch alarms on each of the individual jobs that make up the workflow. The problems with my current solution are that it requires creating many alarms instead of just one, and the alarms fire on a single failure of a job, even if the job succeeds on automatic retry. As far as I can tell there are no Cloudwatch metrics associated with the Workflow like there are for the jobs, so I don't know how I can monitor for Workflow failures.

Comment: Did you find any solution on this one?

Comment: @IgorJanković no, my current plan is to migrate off of Glue Workflows to Step Functions :/